# squid proxy forward domain to IP address with port

Tags: proxy, configuration, squid

I am a bit confuse regarding squid proxy server. The goal is this: if i request a www.website.com and upon request this will be forwarded to an IP address with a port on it (let's say 192.168.0.0:8012) this IP:PORT with an HTTPS on it. How will I apply this to the squid.conf file to run?

Cheers!

Comment: oh yeah, I also forget to mention that I am running this on a container. (rkt in particular)

Comment: Would you mind sharing your attempts to configure squid and/or any particular difficulty you found?

Comment: so, here's the configuration that I currently use:
`acl lan src 192.168.10.0/24                    #client acl for the lan
acl badsites dstdomain .website                #to deny bing.com
deny_info https://192.168.0.0:8012 lan         #Deny with redirect to google.com for lan
http_reply_access deny badsites lan
dns_v4_first on`